# Selenium - Handle dynamic data within a modal window

Tags: java, selenium, modal-dialog, dynamic-data

**Scenario:** There are a list of items displayed in a modal window with a star icon to add chosen item to favorites. 
I need to add few items (randomly) to the favorites and verify if they are added to the favorites.

**My approach:** I am filtering out the non-starred items by using List of Webelements and clicking on star icon (by using Index) to add them to the list. Given below is the code piece

```
Actions obj = new Actions(driver);
obj.click(nonFavoriteInstruments.get(1)).build().perform();
obj.click(nonFavoriteInstruments.get(2)).build().perform();
```

**Issue:** Within the modal, there is a scroll which need not be clicked always. If the non-favorite filter items are out of the display view, I need to scroll down.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec2bO.png)

Can someone help me as to how to handle this scenario? Thanks in advance.

Also, please note that the items remain in the same position even when they are added to favorites. It does not move up in the modal window.

~Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This will scroll until the element is in view :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
Thread.sleep(500);
```

or you can use the Action

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("my-id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions obj = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element = nonFavoriteInstruments.get(1);
obj.moveToElement(element).click(element).build().perform();
obj = new Actions(driver);
element = nonFavoriteInstruments.get(2);


obj.moveToElement(element).click(element).build().perform();
```